# Userform - copy when clicking the button

Tags: vb.net, userform

So, ahm, I'm probably the newest fella around here and I need to ask you something. I've made a really simple application in VB excel and wanted to turn it into a more real application using Visual Studio. 
The purpose of the application is simple. I want to click on a button and when I click it data will be copied.

i.e 
Data:
Hello Everybody and welcome to my community.

Task:
Copy it when clicked on the button.

In excel I just typed down my texts and then recorded some macros. Afterwards I built a userform with VB and then copied/pasted the macro codes and voila. That was it. I suppose though that It is not THAT simple in Visual studio so here I am asking for your assistance if possible :)

Any ideas on how to do this? Which database should I add? How to add the text and then make it copy what's in there.

Comment: If it is in Excel, it is vba/excel-vba not VB.NET

Comment: It is in visual studio actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear about what you're asking, but it seems to me that you want to find text from some source, and then copy it somewhere (textbox, button, message box in the form?). I would have the text saved in a .txt or .INI file. Then, using a stream reader, locate the text and save it in a variable in your visual studio project. You can then use this to copy anywhere in your form. If you have multiple sections of text storing different phrases under different headers in the INI file (ie a section for greetings, a section for goodbyes, a section for questions, etc) I would employ two public functions instead. The first one can be defined as such:

```
    Public Function GetIniValue(ByVal section As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal filename As String, Optional ByVal defaultValue As String = "") As String
```

Where the section is the collection of phrases (greetings, goodbyes, etc), key is the key for the individual phrase in the section (greeting1, greeting2, etc), and filename is the name of the INI file. This function calls the built in function `GetPrivateProfileString` which returns the index where the text is located, and then uses this location to find the text. To use this function, you will need to import a DLL called `kernel32` which should already be on your computer.